# Check if string is hex that starts with "0x..." Perl

Tags: perl, hex

How would I check if a string:

1. Starts with "0x"
2. Is a valid hex number

So for example:

```
# Returns false
$string = "0213"

# Returns false
$string = "0xHHH"

# Returns true
$string = "0x123456789abcdefABCDEF"
```

Comment: This is pretty straightforward, it might be useful to look through a pattern matching tutorial for Perl. A few other questions: What have you tried so far? What makes up a "valid" hexadecimal number?

Comment: With a regular expression. `man perlre`

Comment: There is a Data::Validate `is_hex` method that you could look at, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following operation returns a Boolean value.

```
$string =~ /^0x[0-9A-F]+$/i
```

Comment: There's also `[:xdigit:]` and `\p{PosixXDigit}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this and not reinvent the wheel :-)

```
use Regexp::Common qw(number);
print "$string is hex\n" if $string =~ /^0x$RE{num}{int}{-base => 16}{-sign => ''}$/i
```

You can find more information in [the documentation of Regexp::Common::number](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/ABIGAIL/Regexp-Common-2013031301/lib/Regexp/Common/number.pm). This pattern above is for hexadecimal integers, you can allow or restrict more variants using options of the module.